# Unable to send email on error from logback

Tags: java, logback

I am doing a POC to send email using logback and Java 8. On error we want to send an email to the user so i referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833680/logback-smtpappender-not-sending-email) and my full configuration :

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class App {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
        logger.trace("trace message");
        logger.warn("warn message");
        logger.error("error message, a very long error message!");
    }
}
```

My logback.xml looks like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds">
 <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
        <username>xxx@gmail.com</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <smtpPort>25</smtpPort>
        <to>xxx@gmail.com</to>
        <from>xxx@gmail.com</from>
        <STARTTLS>true</STARTTLS>
        <asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>
        <subject>Testing %logger
        {20}

        - %m</subject>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%d
                {HH:mm:ss.SSS}

                [%thread] %-5level %logger
                {1}

                -%msg%n
            </pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I see when I run main class the configuration is hanging. I do not see any error messages also. Kindly suggest.

**UPDATE:**
OK ... I see that the port 25 or 587 throws the following error I have also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242838/log4j-failing-to-send-an-email-when-logging-an-error) :

```
20:07:02,050 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[EMAIL] - Error occurred while sending e-mail notification. javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587
    at  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.net.SMTPAppenderBase.sendBuffer(SMTPAppenderBase.java:388)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.net.SMTPAppenderBase.append(SMTPAppenderBase.java:212)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase.doAppend(AppenderBase.java:82)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:270)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:257)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:421)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.error(Logger.java:538)
    at  at com.email.example.App.main(App.java:18)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at  at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
    at  at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    at  ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Am I missing something here? one point I want to mention is the from and to address are same, not sure if that matters.

Comment: This might help https://logback.qos.ch/recipes/emailPerTransaction.html

Comment: Did you check your antivirus?

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue I have macfee, I tried disabling the email scanner option still same.

Comment: Request to send mail is attempting to connect to SMTP host, because of which you don't see any errors or exceptions. Setting timeout will help you. Also check if you are able to connect to Gmail's SMTP server using JAVA Mail API to verify that you are able to connect SMTP server, to rule out permission and firewall issues.

Comment: Indeed it was an issue with Anti-virus ...